# Adding references to other projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with 4 projects in it.

Test.Common
Test.Controller (Controllers for the Web project)
Test.Data (EntityFramework)
Test.Web (MVC4)

When I go to add a reference to my Data layer to my Controller project and browse to my Data project's directory, should I be using the dll from the 'bin/Debug' directory or the 'obj' directory? And, does it make a difference?

Comment: You should add reference by project. Switch to the Project tab in the Add Reference window and select the project you wish to reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither.

You should add a Project reference (from the Solution section)

This will make Visual Studio resolve the reference from the project system, making features like Go to Definition and automatic rebuild work.

---

Outside your solution, you should add from bin.

Answer (score 7):

You should be adding a reference to the Project in question, not its output. There is a 'Projects' tab on the 'Add Reference' dialog.

Answer (score 4):

If the project is in your current solution you can make a reference to the project (**Class Library**) itself. This will offload the responsibility of configuration management (Debug, Release, etc) to Visual Studio.