# Activate class form another library with button

Tags: c#, console-application

i refer to this image: [image]

the blue arrow, is where i have a button, on a normal website.

but i want to be able to run the file ( red arrow) by pressing the button. 
it's a console app that gets data from one db to another.

this is the button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update Database!", "value", "value", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg active" })
```

but i have no idea what to place in the "values" ??...

i really hope im making sense..

**Edit**:

I ended up creating an entirely new project, "shared" where i added my console app. alot of work. and seems a bit much. but it works..

Comment: did you add reference of Import project to Data ?

Comment: where should i do that ? i have a couple of models, in data that i have using on in import.

Comment: add a reference 'Import' to the Data

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927242/adding-references-to-other-projects-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: where should that reference be placed at ?

Comment: @andrelange91 go to References ==> add reference ==> project ==> select the data project and in your button class `using Tick_timeupdata.Import` then you can call it

Answer (score 0):

I assume the red arrow show the `Program.cs` file which is belong to a `tick_timeupdate.Import` console app.

I assume Your buton is on the web site.

So i assume...

...You want to run `tick_timeupdate.Import` app from web site You need do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Process.Start(@"Path_To_Your_Console_App_EXE_File");
    return View();
}
```

You don't need to add references from `References->Add Project References` from `Solution Explorer` winodw.

**But**

If You don't want to run console app from web site - You may add references and create constructor of Program class. In the constructor You can add parameters as You like.

[image]

Comment: i created an entire new "shared" project, and add all the info and program into that. because i already had references from timeupdate to import, but not the other way around. Which i have been told, i cannot have both.